# Is it possible to eliminate name mangling in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I know I can eliminate ID mangling in ASP.NET 4.0, but can I also eliminate name mangling? This looks like the best I can do:

```
<input name="ctl00$body$txtName" type="text" id="txtName" />
```

Is that correct?

Comment: What's your reason for doing this?

Comment: Name attribute matters only to the FORM (by default, unless you re-purposed it), and it does not have to be unique at all - not even within a single FORM tag. So, I don't see the reason why you even want that. But, what do you even mean by "mangling"? Making sure it's unique? You can always use GUIDs, or something similar.

Comment: The front end guy I'm working with on this page says that's our standard for this site and "name" is how he's referencing the controls (jQuery, I think). So, I'm just researching it so I can give him a definitive answer regarding whether or not it's possible. If this is the best I can do, I'll take that answer to him, and we'll figure out an alternative way to deal with things.

Comment: What I mean by mangling is that we set the attribute like this: name="txtName" and .NET turns it into this: name="ctl00$body$txtName".

Comment: asp.net wont' do that to your controls for their "name" attribute. It only does it for "id" attributes, because those need to be unique on the page (you may have controls at different levels, at the same page, with exact same server IDs; so asp.net is helping you creating nightmares of client-side errors, if those are left intact). Jquery support selecting elements by id and various other ways that involve identifying them by existence and values of their attributes and even child elements

Comment: Why not use client ID (at the server: control.ClientID; also see control.UniqueID) - especially, since what you want to make for name values almost looks like ClientID, or is exactly equivalent to "UniqueID" that every server control has.

Comment: I'm really just looking for an answer to my original question, and it looks like the answer is that it is not possible to eliminate name mangling in ASP.NET 4.0. Thanks!

Comment: im pretty sure u did something to achieve totally the opossite: name does not get prepended parent controls' names delimited with dollar signs. are u sure asp.net is doing that and not ur code burried in some mangled base class or something? i actually havent touched webforms with .net4, but i'm sure what you are saying is happening wasn't the case with earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET relies on name mangling to route posted form data to input controls in nested naming containers. The ways to avoid name mangling are:

1. Don't use nested naming containers such as master pages or user controls. Input controls that are placed directly on an .aspx page will have simple names.
2. Don't use the standard ASP.NET input controls. Instead, you could:

   - Put `<input type="text" name="name" />` (without `runat="server"`) in the .ascx/.aspx and access its value via `Request.Form["name"]`.
   - Create a custom server control that does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's the deal.  I needed to change the values of form elements dynamically (server side), I need to keep the MasterPage, and I have panels on the page as well.  There is no way around it.

What I have done instead, is use server side "yellow tags", and public variables:

HTML:

```
<input type='hidden' name='x_login' id='x_login' value="<%= x_login %>" />
```

Code:

```
Public x_login As String = "some value"
```

And to access the value after a postback:

```
Request.Form("x_login")
```

Thanks to Michael Liu's answer for the very last bit there.  I've upvoted his answer just for that reason.